# Android ImageView animation up not working

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm building an app and i wanted to animate some `imageView` element. The problem is that at the end of the animation, the element gets an unexpected boost in the y axis, instead the defined one.

I know that at the end of the animation process the animated element returns to its original x,y. I manually added the animated offset at the `onAnimationEnd` method. For some odd reason the animated element jumps about 40 pixels up, and I know I didnt add it anywhere  by mistake. Whats wrong here?

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView logo,moto;
    private int[] imageView_XY;
    public float logoXpos,logoYpos;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verification_activity);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        //animates the logo
        animate(logo,30);
    }

    public void animate(final ImageView imageView, int amount){
        //gets the current x,y of the widget
        imageView_XY = new int[2];
        imageViewElement.getLocationInWindow(imageView_XY);
        logoXpos = (int) imageViewElement.getX();
        logoYpos = imageView_XY[1];
        Log.d("Animation XY: "," current location "+"("+logoXpos+","+logoYpos+")"); //prints out 0,0
        //animates the widget 100 px up
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-amount);
        logoAnim.setDuration(1000);
        logoAnim.setFillAfter(false);

        logoAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("Animation: ","animation ended");
                logoXpos = imageView_XY[0];
                logoYpos = imageView_XY[1];
                Log.d("Animation ended XY: "," current location "+"("+logoXpos+","+logoYpos+")"); //prints out 0,0 again
                imageViewElement.setY(logoYpos+30);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("Animation: ","animation repeat");
            }
        });
        imageViewElement.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks steve, after a good sleep i figured it wasnt the smartest thing to add to the callback :) Also, had to set the setFillAfter to true in order to keep the animated elements at place. Weird thing though, I'm not able to animate that element back to its original place when I call the animate method on the backPressed method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got this working. For future googlers:
I ended up setting the `logoAnim.setFillAfter(false);` to `true` and got rid of the manual shift at the end of the animation `imageViewElement.setY(logoYpos+30);`.